# Gradle run multiple spring projects with conditions

Tags: spring, gradle

I have multiple projects witch using spring and spring boot.
Spring boot have command to run application with Gradle:

```
gradle bootRun
```

I can run all my applications with command:

```
gradle bootRun --parallel
```

But I need one of my projects(Lets call it project A) to be started first, and only after it(project A) started other projects could start too.

Problem is, I don't understand how I can start project A, then wait till it started, and only after it start other projects.

If I just chain task it won't work because project A keep running and not giving back control to gradle.

Grdale config for one of the projects:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    group 'test one'    
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    )
}
```

Main setting.gradle just contains list of my projects:

```
rootProject.name = 'best-app'    
include 'project A'
include 'project B'
include 'project C'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one task that waits until `A` is booted fully and then finishes, then make all `bootRun` tasks except the one of `A` depend on this task.

---

**Update 2023:**

In the meantime `A` should now better be a [Shared Build Service](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_services.html) instead.

Comment: but i thought the author say very clearly "If I just chain task it won't work because project A keep running and not giving back control to gradle."  Hence how would your solution then works?

Comment: @NickWills Yes, I didn't say he should simply chain the tasks. I said he should have one task (in a different project than `A` as it can then also run at the same time with the `--parallel` OP is using) that waits for `A` not to finish but to have booted the server to a point the other tasks need and then this spectator task will finish. The other tasks needing `A` then will depend on that spectator task that finishes after `A` is "ready enough". Besides that nowadays at least `A` should be a shared build service instead.